# Homomorphism Group From $S_3$ to $\Bbb Z_5 \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$. Given that
$$S_3=\{f:A \to A \mid \text{$f$ is a bijective function}\}$$
is a group under composition of function.
Let $\Bbb Z_5^*=\{\bar{x} \in \Bbb Z \mid \bar{x} \ne \bar{0}\}$ is a group under multiplication modulo $5$. Define a map $P:S_3 \to \Bbb Z_5^*$ by
$P(a)=\overline{a(1)}$ for all $a \in S_3$. Determine whether $P$ is a group homomorphism.

**Attempt:**

**EDIT:**

Consider
$$a=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
b=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \in S_3.$$
We obtain
$$P(a \circ b)=\overline{(a \circ b)(1)}=\overline{a(b(1))}=\overline{a(2)}=\overline{1}\ne \overline{4}=\overline{2} \cdot \overline{2}=\overline{a(1)} \cdot \overline{b(1)}=P(a) \cdot P(b).$$
Hence, $P$ is not a group homomorphism.

Is it correct?
Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: $ab(1) = a(b(1))$.

Comment: @EthanBolker What about the edit?

Comment: That looks good (quick read).

Comment: @EthanBolker OK, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.

Another idea. If $P$ is a homomorphism, then $o(P(a))\mid o(a)$ for every $a\in S_3$. Take $a=(12)$; then, $P(a)=\bar 2$; but $o(\bar 2)=4\nmid 2=o(a)$. So, $P$ is not a homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\Bbb Z_5^*$.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty good.

Or, what would the kernel be?   $\rm ker(P)=\{a\in S_3\mid P(a)=1\}=\{a\in S_3\mid a(1)=1\}=\{e,(23)\}\cong S_2.$

But then $\lvert \rm im(P)\rvert =3\not\mid 4=\lvert \Bbb Z_5^*\rvert\rightarrow\leftarrow.$

Or, $S_2$ isn't normal in $S_3.$

Comment: I hope the OP gets the notion `-><-` showing a contradiction!:)